# Get Windows 10 - always says downloading in background, but is not actually

Tags: windows-10

My get windows 10 box has shown downloading in background for about 2 days, but it does not appear to actually be downloading. If I click on the show status button, the window just disappears.  I've tried disabling my viruscan software, no change.  I've done some searches and found that Win 8.1 (which I currently have) update issues can cause this. I've had numerous 8.1 updates that have not been able to install for about 3 weeks. They always get a "we could not complete the updates" during reboot and install and they back themselves out.  I've tried numerous reboots, updating one at a time, and other options that I've run across in my searches.  Nothing seems to work.  My computer is less than 6 months old and came pre-installed with 8.1.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try to download it with the Windows 10 Media Creation tool

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue pretty much - for months Windows update would successfully install updates but on restart it would display something like 'Failed to configure updates' and revert the changes, and Windows 10 wouldn't download as a result.

I know you said you tried installing the updates individually but what worked for me was **hiding all updates then un-hiding around 4 at a time** (I couldn't be bothered to do one at a time as I had 26 updates to do haha), letting them install then restarting. (Hiding the updates prevented Windows from installing all the updates automatically on restart despite only selecting some of them.) I didn't actually need to do all the updates before the Windows 10 update appeared in Windows Update as I think one of those updates starts the Windows 10 download.
Also while installing the updates as explained above I had my antivirus disabled (which you said you had tried) and I performed a '**clean boot**' - basically disabling all startup items in Task Manager and disabling all non-Microsoft services in msconfig. (More info: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/929135) Not sure if that made a difference though.

The other thing I was going to try was putting Windows 10 onto a USB drive using the official Microsoft tool (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install) and installing it from there, although I didn't need to do that in the end.

Hope this helps!